# making this view for Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle10g

This view in SQL Server is getting records which we then display according to admin time, I need to do this in Oracle 10g now, what sort of differences do I have to convert for here?

```
    /* Formatted on 1/29/2013 3:39:19 PM (QP5 v5.227.12220.39724) */
SELECT p.facility_key,
       CAST (p.unit_code AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST (p.room AS VARCHAR)
      AS unit_code,
       p.first_name,
       p.last_name,
       m.admin_time,
     CONVERT (varchar (5),
            datediff (s,
                  m.admin_time,
                  getdate ())
          / 3600)
       + ':'
       + CONVERT (varchar (5),
          datediff (s,
                m.admin_time,
                getdate ())% 3600 / 60)
              AS ELAPSED
FROM         OTEN.TEN_M_PATIENT_MAST AS P INNER JOIN
              OP.ORD_M_ADMIN AS M ON P.PAT_NUMBER = M.PAT_NUMBER
WHERE     (M.ADMIN_TIME BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, - 1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
```

Comment: Have you tried it in Oracle to see what works/breaks?

Comment: yes 'missing left parenthasis' after the first cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your elapsed time is less than 24 hours, then the following should work:

```
SELECT P.FACILITY_KEY,
       CAST(P.UNIT_CODE AS VARCHAR(255)) || '-' || CAST(P.ROOM AS VARCHAR(255)) AS UNIT_CODE,
       P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME, M.ADMIN_TIME,
       to_char(trunc(sysdate)+(SYSDATE - m.admin_time), 'hh:mm:ss') as elapsed
FROM OTEN.TEN_M_PATIENT_MAST P INNER JOIN
     OP.ORD_M_ADMIN M
     ON P.PAT_NUMBER = M.PAT_NUMBER
WHERE M.ADMIN_TIME BETWEEN sysdate - 1 and sysdate
```

Some notes.  First, I added a length to `varchar`.  You should do this in any database.  Second, I simplified the datetime arithmetic to just use subtraction.  I changed `getdate()` to `sysdate`.  And the "+"s with "||"s.  Finally, to get the elapsed time in hh:mm:ss format, I used a trick.  I take the difference, add to the current date, and just convert the fractional part to hh:mm:ss.

Comment: thanks for answer, not sure why they close it.

Comment: I totally disagree.  So, i voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 /* Formatted on 1/29/2013 4:00:43 PM (QP5 v5.227.12220.39724) */
SELECT p.facility_key,
       CAST (p.unit_code AS VARCHAR) || '-' || CAST (p.room AS VARCHAR)
      AS unit_code,
       p.first_name,
       p.last_name,
       m.admin_time,
     TO_CHAR (  (SYSDATE- m.admin_time)
          / 3600)
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR ((SYSDATE- m.admin_time) MOD 3600 / 60)
              AS elapsed
FROM         oten.ten_m_patient_mast  p INNER JOIN
              op.ord_m_admin m ON p.pat_number = m.pat_number
WHERE     (m.admin_time BETWEEN (SYSDATE -1) AND SYSDATE)
```